# 3? ways in scala to return a function from a function - 1 doesn't compile - don't understand why

Tags: function, scala

I'm learning Scala.  I have a Scala function which can return another function. I've come across 3 ways to do this in Scala (there may be more).  In this particular code the 3rd option doesn't seem to compile but I've seen this technique used elsewhere but can't work out why it isn't working in this case.

In this fairly contrived example I have a function that takes an Int and returns a function that maps an Int to Boolean.

```
  def intMapper1(elem: Int): Int => Boolean = {
    def mapper(x: Int): Boolean =
      x == elem
    mapper
  }

  def intMapper2(elem: Int): Int => Boolean = (x: Int) => x == elem

  def intMapper3(elem: Int)(x: Int) = x == elem

  val m1 = intMapper1(2)
  val m2 = intMapper2(4)
  val m3 = intMapper3(6)
```

I get the compile error:
Error:(35, 22) missing arguments for method intMapper3 in object FunSets;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
  val m3 = intMapper3(6)
                     ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `def intMapper3(elem: Int)(x: Int) = x == elem`  has two parameter list, you are passing only one parameter(i.e. elem), the second parameter (x) is missing here. And `intMapper3` is not a `higher order function`. It is not taking any function as argument and not returning a function. It is a normal method, taking two parameter list and returns a Boolean value.

You can derive a partially applied function from m3 as  `val m3 = intMapper3(6)_`. That is what compiler telling you.

Comment: Ah okay, so by adding the _ to the first call I can make it behave effectively the same as intMapper1/2. Was sure I'd tried that but guess not.

Out of interest, why do you say intMapper3 is not a higher order function? The example I followed was in a Coursera course describing higher order functions and currying, and it showed the transformation from something like intMapper1 to intMapper2 (simpler using anonymous function) to intMapper3 (simpler and more concise). Isn't it effectively returning a function because you can use it as a partially applied function?

Answer (score 1):

Your Method `def intMapper3(elem: Int)(x: Int) = x == elem` is a simple function in scala. it takes two parameters "elem" and "x" and computes the result.

It can be used as :

```
scala> intMapper3(2)(2)
res2: Boolean = true
scala> intMapper3(2)(1)
res3: Boolean = false
```

But if you pass only one argument it will show an error because intMapper3 requires two parameters.

"intMapper1" function can be called in these following ways:

```
scala> intMapper1(1)(2)
res0: Boolean = false
scala> intMapper1(1)(1)
res1: Boolean = true
```

In this case the output of "intMapper1" is a function that takes and  argument of Int type and returns a boolean result.

```
scala> val m1 = intMapper1(2)
m1: Int => Boolean = <function1>    
scala> m1(2)
res1: Boolean = true
```